# How to open a pdf file in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf file in vuejs

```
<base-button tag="a" color="white" class="mt-4" href="../../static/application_form.pdf">
      Application Form
</base-button>
```

But the pdf file is not opening. It show this in the URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/static/application_form.pdf#/
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is due to hash symbol, please change your VueRouter mode:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
});
```